# Solve the inequality $x^2+y^2 \geq\frac{1}{x+y}+2(x-y -1).$

Tags: inequality

For which real values  $x,y$ does the inequality $x^2+y^2 \geq\frac{1}{x+y}+2(x-y -1)$  hold?

I have found for $x=\dfrac{1}{10}, y=\dfrac{3}{10}$  that  LHS=RHS  but cant solve it in the general case.   Here is 3d-plot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The rational cubic
$$(x+y)(x^2+y^2)-1-2(x+y)(x-y-1)=0\tag{1}$$
splits $\mathbb{R}^2$ in two parts, corresponding to the values for which the inequality holds or not.

The support of such a cubic is quite close to the line $(x+y)=0$:

$\hspace2in$[image]

It is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve $4v^3+4u^2v-1=0$ with discriminant $-1456$.